# GCP App Engine Showing 5XX errors in usage but does not show up in GAE App Logs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

This image shows Summary of App Engine Usage that has 2.28 Server(5XX) around 9:03AM:

[image: here]

This image shows logs of the GAE application which seems to skip between 9:00AM - 9:08AM

[image: here]

Is there anything I need to look into to know why these are happening?  We have been getting user reports that they are receiving 502 errors on our application.

Comment: Are you running on Standard or Flexible environment? If on Flexible, do you see any error around that time in the "Cloud HTTP Load Balancer" section of the Logging page in your Dev Console? This may give you some hint about the issue if it was coming from the load balancer not able to reach GAE instances for some reason.